# Button click is not working in IE11

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a upload button in IE11.it is not working tried with below ways.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)  new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver()).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+SelectFiles.getLocation().y+")");

((JavascriptExecutor)  driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+element.getLocation().x+")");
```

only through Javascript executor it is working fine.

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Element);*/
```

but if I use javascript executor code to click element cursor I mean script is not moving to next statement. Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Could you paste the html code of the button you are trying to click?

Comment: <input id="$PpyAttachmentPage$ppxAttachName" class="" type="file" contenteditable="false" onchange="triggerRefresh(this,true, event);" size="25" value="" name="$PpyAttachmentPage$ppxAttachName" multiple=""/>

Comment: I am using //*[contains(@id,'AttachmentPage')] this xpath and it is in Iframe so i switched to iframe and trying to click on it.The same code is working in Firefox